# How to display and update a score on screen with Tkinter?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm creating a Flappy Bird like.
However, I would like to create a score like the real game that would appear on the screen. But after researching Google, I have not found anyone wishing to increase a score on the screen ...

Indeed, I would like the score to increase each time the bird passes between the pipes and therefore whenever the pipes have an X of 67 pixels. So does anyone know how to do this?

Could someone explain the problem to me because I thought it would be easy :( Here are the pictures of the game :)

[Here are the pictures of the game](http://www.mediafire.com/file/nr1a1qmfsh6s8s4/Flappy+Bird.zip)

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from random import randint

def sauter(event):
    canvas.move(image_oiseau, 0, -10*DY)


def deplacement():
    global tuyx,tuyx2,h,H,oisx,oisy,solx,sol2x

    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.bbox(image_oiseau)
    if y1 < 416:
        canvas.move(image_oiseau, 0, DY)

    canvas.coords(image_sol,solx,512)  
    if solx >= -144:
        solx=solx-5
    else:
        solx=144

    canvas.coords(image_sol2,sol2x,512)
    if sol2x >= 144:
        sol2x=sol2x-5
    else:
        sol2x=432

    canvas.coords(image_tuyau_haut,tuyx,h)
    canvas.coords(image_tuyau_bas,tuyx,h-241)
    if tuyx>=-28:
        tuyx=tuyx-5
    else:
        tuyx=316
        h=randint(256,505)

    canvas.coords(image_tuyau_haut2,tuyx2,H)
    canvas.coords(image_tuyau_bas2,tuyx2,H-241)
    if tuyx2>=-28:
        tuyx2=tuyx2-5
    else:
        tuyx2=316
        H=randint(256,505)

    canvas.after(40,deplacement)


LARGEUR = 286
HAUTEUR = 510
DY = 5
tuyx=316
tuyx2=488 
h=randint(256,505)
H=randint(256,505)
oisx=67
oisy=244
solx=144
sol2x=432


fenetre = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(fenetre, width=LARGEUR, height=HAUTEUR)

fond = PhotoImage(file="background-day.png")
fond2 = PhotoImage(file="background-night.png")
fond=[fond,fond2]
F= random.choice(fond)
canvas.create_image(144,256, anchor=CENTER,image=F)

tuyau_haut = PhotoImage(file="tuyau_vers_le_haut.png")
image_tuyau_haut = canvas.create_image(tuyx,h,anchor=CENTER,image=tuyau_haut)
image_tuyau_haut2 = canvas.create_image(tuyx2,H,anchor=CENTER,image=tuyau_haut)

tuyau_bas = PhotoImage(file="tuyau_vers_le_bas.png")
image_tuyau_bas = canvas.create_image(tuyx,h,anchor=CENTER,image=tuyau_bas)
image_tuyau_bas2 = canvas.create_image(tuyx2,H,anchor=CENTER,image=tuyau_bas)

sol = PhotoImage(file="sol-day.png")
image_sol = canvas.create_image(144,512, anchor=S,image=sol)
image_sol2 = canvas.create_image(432,512, anchor=S,image=sol)

oiseau = PhotoImage(file="yellowbird-midflap.png")
oiseau2 = PhotoImage(file="bluebird-midflap.png")
oiseau3 = PhotoImage(file="redbird-midflap.png")
oiseau=[oiseau,oiseau2,oiseau3]
O=random.choice(oiseau)
image_oiseau=canvas.create_image(oisx,oisy, anchor=W,image=O) 

deplacement()

canvas.pack()
canvas.focus_set()
canvas.bind("<space>",sauter) 

fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use `canvas.create_text(x, y , text="Score")` or use `Label()` widget.

Comment: You've asked the same question 3 hours ago. You must allow time for people to understand what you want precisely - some clarifications were requested in the comments - and time for answers to come forth.

Comment: I know but you said that my question was unclear :o I saw the clarifications requested in the comments, that's why I asked the same question but not the same title ;)

Comment: Yes, you have not replied - you can reply in the comments, and/or edit your question to refine, and clarify it.

Comment: I'm new so I didn't know that. thanks ! I'm goign to change that ;)

Comment: There is a tutorial you can follow to get acquainted with the site: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Further, some of your previous questions have been answered, but you did not give feedback. If the answer suits you, you should accept it; if not, you should give feedback in order to get a better answer.

Comment: I will read that and delete that question then: D
Thank you for your help Reblochon Masque!

Comment: Okay, so I'd like to thank you for your response this morning and your program which was very helpful to my understanding of the program!

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad I could help.

Comment: Okay, I did it, I accepted your answer ;)
Good job elsewhere.